# ADB how to use/start system calls

Tags: android, shell, debugging, adb, root

Goal: So I have ADB device is rooted and I need to turn on the Vibrator motor, or Flashlight.

As an example:
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE

This launches the camera. Where can I find these actions? and how do I execute them?

Answer (score 0):

Those are intents, which is a messaging object you can use to request an action from another app component.

Although intents facilitate communication between components in several ways, there are three fundamental use cases:

- starting an Activity
- starting a Service
- delivering a Broadcast

The list of common intents can be found at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common